# Ranking user score in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an array which consists of 600 records in the format of:

```
[ Mac     14
  John    12
  abc     12  
  bill    16  ]
```

I am trying to create a ranking model for the above, in the sense the bill has rank1, mac as rank 2, john, abc as rank3 and push it back to the array. Example as

```
[ Mac     14  2
  John    12  3
  abc     12  3
  bill    16  1 ]
```

Below is the code which i have tried:

```
    var items = data.d.results;

if(items.length > 0){
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
 playerDetails.push( items[i].Title , items[i].Points );    
 }
 var scores = playerDetails.map(function(d) { return d[1]; }).sort().reverse();
   console.log(playerDetails);
```

The initial playerdetails array contains the data in the format of:

```
{John, Nikhil C.,467},{Cule, Mac A.,341},{Pat, Ryan,465}

  [
      [0...99]: [
         [0...9]: [
            0: "{John, Nikhil C.",
            1: "467}",
            2: "{Cule, Mac A.",
            3: "341}",
            4: "{Pat, Ryan",
            5: "465}",

         ],
```

Is this possible in jQuery? If yes, how to achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is possible in javascript, no jQuery required.

This example introduces a new array of scores, for sorting purposes:

```
var data = [['Mac', 14],['John', 12],['abc',12],['bill',16]];

var scores = data.map(d => d[1]).sort().reverse();
data = data.map(d => d.concat([scores.indexOf(d[1])+1]));
```

If you don't mind your entire dataset to be sorted based on score, you could do the manipulation entirely within the original data. You could then use the current posiiton in the iteration for rank, and only check for the corner case that the current item is ranking the same as the previous:

```
data
  .sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1])
  .forEach((d,i,a) => d.push(i > 0 && a[i-1][1] == d[1] ? a[i-1][2] : i+1));
```

Comment: I looked up the map function but can only find one where the callback is passed, I can't figure out what d => d[1] is doing here, can you please provide an explanation or a link?

Comment: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is an ECMAScript 6 shorthand for function declarations. It is available in [all modern browsers except IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions), but mostly I find it useful to convey ideas in this forum without cluttering the code with a verbose syntax. You can rewrite `map(d => d[1])` as `map(function(d) { return d[1]; })`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the code and I am getting "Syntax error in line: var scores = playerDetails.map(d => d[1]).sort().reverse();

Comment: In that case you are perhaps running IE or an old browser that doesn't support the aforementioned arrow functions. Does `var score = playerDetails.map(function(d) { return d[1]; }).sort().reverse()` give the same error?

Comment: Hi. The above line works : var scores = playerDetails.map(function(d) { return d[1]; }).sort().reverse();

Comment: OK, an issue is that your `playerDetails` array isn't in a very useful format. Why are you adding `{` and `}`? Try instead `playerDetails.push([items[i].Title, items[i].Points]);`, but to be honest, it looks like `items` is in a fine format, and why would you create `playerDetails` rather than just use `items` directly?

Comment: Hi @DavidHedlund, I have updated the code. Could you please have a look . I want the Rank calculated and added back to the playerDetails array

Comment: Hi. Any help on this? I have updated my code, but it is not working.

Comment: My last comment still applies.